# Keeps giving error Undefined variable Framework Routing [OPEN]

Tags: php, .htaccess, controller, url-routing

**Keeps giving error Undefined variable Framework Routing**

I need to make a simple routing system.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _server in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 2

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\index.php on line 3
```

*Check whether the requested controller exists and if so, 'include' it.
Check if the requested method exists, and if so, call it.
Include only the controller that is important for that URL
If the controller does not exist, print a 404 Not found message.
If the method does not exist, print a 404 Not found message.
Also return a 404 status code for 404 pages.*

It keeps giving an error with undefining a variable, and when i `/` to a page it keeps giving this error.

***Down here are the files i use.***

```
<?php
$linkExplode = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (empty($linkExplode[1] && empty($linkExplode[2]))) {
    $linkExplode[1] = 'Home';
    $linkExplode[2] = 'index';
}
$controller = empty($linkExplode[1]) ? 'home' : $linkExplode[1];
$method = empty($linkExplode[2]) ? 'index' : $linkExplode[2];
if (file_exists('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Homecontroller.class.php')) {
    require('./Controllers/' . ucfirst($controller) . 'UserController.class.php');
    $classname = ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
    $class = new $classname();

    if (method_exists($class, $method)) {
        $class->$method();
    } else {
        http_response_code(404);
        die;
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    die;
}
```

***HomeController***

```
<?php
class HomeController
{
    public function index() 
    {
        echo 'De home pagina!';
    }
}
```

***UserController***

```
<?php
class UserController
{
    public function login() 
    {
        echo 'De login pagina!';
    }
}
```

***Htacces***

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ src/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
DirectoryIndex src/index.php
```

***Currently Var_Dumping $_SERVER Giving this back***

```
array(58) { ["REDIRECT_MIBDIRS"]=> string(24) "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["REDIRECT_MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["REDIRECT_OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31) "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["REDIRECT_PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["REDIRECT_PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["REDIRECT_TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=> string(3) "200" ["MIBDIRS"]=> string(24) "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs" ["MYSQL_HOME"]=> string(16) "\xampp\mysql\bin" ["OPENSSL_CONF"]=> string(31) "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf" ["PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["PHPRC"]=> string(10) "\xampp\php" ["TMP"]=> string(10) "\xampp\tmp" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA"]=> string(64) ""Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE"]=> string(2) "?0" ["HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM"]=> string(9) ""Windows"" ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(114) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(135) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"]=> string(10) "cross-site" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE"]=> string(8) "navigate" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER"]=> string(2) "?1" ["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST"]=> string(8) "document" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip, deflate, br" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(35) "nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(36) "PHPSESSID=auct5lh5cga85hmln0o54kfjf4" ["PATH"]=> string(964) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\PHP;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\jeann\Pictures\gradle-7.1.1\bin;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\jeann\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin" ["SystemRoot"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" ["COMSPEC"]=> string(27) "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" ["PATHEXT"]=> string(53) ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" ["WINDIR"]=> string(10) "C:\WINDOWS" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(95) "
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11 Server at localhost Port 80
" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(47) "Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(3) "::1" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4) "http" ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(20) "postmaster@localhost" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(29) "C:/xampp/htdocs/src/index.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "51472" ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(11) "/user/login" ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(14) "url=user/login" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(14) "url=user/login" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(11) "/user/login" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(14) "/src/index.php" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(14) "/src/index.php" ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1636987064.7515) ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1636987064) }
```

Comment: PHP variables are case-sensitive, you are looking for `$_SERVER`, not `$_server`

Comment: @ChrisHaas yeah thanks, but now it doesnt load the page at all mate.

Comment: After line 2, put a dump on `$linkExplode` to see what's in there.

Comment: @ChrisHaas ```array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }```

Comment: So then dump `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER`

Comment: @ChrisHaas Its giving a big error i dont understand doesnt look like a normal Var_dump.

Comment: You'll have to post the error for us to help. Please edit your original question with what you tried, and what output you received.